# bash scripting tab

Tags: bash, scripting, escaping

I'm a newbie in Bash scripting.

Here is the command included in the script:

`arecacli64 disk info` gives usualy:

```
  # Ch# ModelName                       Capacity  Usage

===============================================================================
  1  1  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  2  2  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  3  3  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  4  4  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  5  5  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  6  6  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  7  7  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  8  8  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
  9  9  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 10 10  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 11 11  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 12 12  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 13 13  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 14 14  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 15 15  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 16 16  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 17 17  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 18 18  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 19 19  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 20 20  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  HotSpare[Global]
 21 21  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 22 22  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 23 23  ST3750640NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
 24 24  ST3750330NS                      750.2GB  Raid Set # 00   
===============================================================================
```

My simple script is:

```
F=`dmidecode |grep  "Product Name:"|cut -d ":" -f2|head -1`

if [ $F == "X7DB8" ]
then
echo
echo
echo -e "$VERT" HOSTNAME : `hostname`"$NORMAL"
echo -e "$BLEU" TYPE :"$NORMAL" `dmidecode -s system-manufacturer`
echo -e "$BLEU" MODEL :"$NORMAL" `dmidecode -t system |grep "Product Name:"|cut -d ":" -f2`


echo "-------------------->"
echo

echo -e  `/usr/local/bb/ext/Raid/arecacli64 disk info`

fi
```

But the result is displayed (the part concerning the raid ctrl) without any tabs showed by the command `arecalcli64 disk info`

```
 HOSTNAME : xxxx@www.com
 TYPE : Supermicro
 MODEL : X7DB8
-------------------->


  # Ch# ModelName Capacity Usage =============================================================================== ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 2 2 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 3 3 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 4 4 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 5 5 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 6 6 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 7 7 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 8 8 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 9 9 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 10 10 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 11 11 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 12 12 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 13 13 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 14 14 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 15 15 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 16 16 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 17 17 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 18 18 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 19 19 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 20 20 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB HotSpare[Global] 21 21 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 22 22 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 23 23 
ST3750640NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 24 24 
ST3750330NS 750.2GB Raid Set # 00 =============================================================================== GuiErrMsg: Success.
```

I've try with `\t` `\` or with `sed` etc.

Comment: lovely formatting. please edit it.

Comment: Edited to put in normal form.

Answer (score 4):

instead of

```
echo -e  `/usr/local/bb/ext/Raid/arecacli64 disk info`
```

simply use

```
/usr/local/bb/ext/Raid/arecacli64 disk info
```

Answer (score 0):

If you quote the command substitution, you would get the correct output.

```
echo  "`/usr/local/bb/ext/Raid/arecacli64 disk info`"
```

The `-e` flag is not needed, as you aren't specifying any `\t` characters; the
tabs are embedded in the output of `arecacli64` and are preserved by quoting
its output.

But as kkeller pointed out, there's no need to use command substitution in the first place.